# Scraper unable to parse content from first page

Tags: vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I've written some code to parse Name, Address and Phone number of different shops from yell.com. If any link is given to my crawler It parses the whole content irrespective of how many pages it has spread across. However, the only problem I could find out is that it always skips the content of first page, as in if there are 10 pages, my crawler scrapes last 9 pages. A little twitch might lead me to get a workaround. Here is the complete code. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub YellUK()
Const mlink = "https://www.yell.com"
Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument, htm As New HTMLDocument
Dim post As HTMLHtmlElement, page As Object, newlink As String

With http
    .Open "GET", "https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?keywords=pizza&location=United+Kingdom&scrambleSeed=1426936001", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
Set page = html.getElementsByClassName("row pagination")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
For i = 0 To page.Length - 2
    newlink = mlink & Replace(page(i).href, "about:", "")
    With http
        .Open "GET", newlink, False
        .send
        htm.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each post In htm.getElementsByClassName("js-LocalBusiness")
        x = x + 1
        With post.getElementsByClassName("row businessCapsule--title")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
            If .Length Then Cells(x + 1, 1) = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
        With post.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-10 col-md-11 col-lg-12 businessCapsule--address")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")
            If .Length > 1 Then Cells(x + 1, 2) = .Item(1).innerText
        End With
        With post.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-10 col-md-11 col-lg-12 businessCapsule--address")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")
            If .Length > 2 Then Cells(x + 1, 3) = .Item(2).innerText
        End With
        With post.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-10 col-md-11 col-lg-12 businessCapsule--address")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")
            If .Length > 3 Then Cells(x + 1, 4) = .Item(3).innerText
        End With
        With post.getElementsByClassName("businessCapsule--tel")
            If .Length > 1 Then Cells(x + 1, 5) = .Item(1).innerText
        End With
    Next post
Next i
End Sub
```

Here is the elements within which page-number for next page is stored:

```
<div class="row pagination">
<div class="col-sm-24">
&nbsp;<span class="pagination--page is-selected">1</span>
&nbsp;<a class="pagination--page" rel="nofollow" href="/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?location=United+Kingdom&amp;keywords=pizza&amp;scrambleSeed=721890588&amp;pageNum=2" data-tracking="DISPLAY:PAGINATION:NUMBER">2</a>
&nbsp;<a class="pagination--page" rel="nofollow" href="/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?location=United+Kingdom&amp;keywords=pizza&amp;scrambleSeed=721890588&amp;pageNum=3" data-tracking="DISPLAY:PAGINATION:NUMBER">3</a>
&nbsp;<a class="pagination--page" rel="nofollow" href="/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?location=United+Kingdom&amp;keywords=pizza&amp;scrambleSeed=721890588&amp;pageNum=4" data-tracking="DISPLAY:PAGINATION:NUMBER">4</a>
&nbsp;<a class="pagination--page" rel="nofollow" href="/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?location=United+Kingdom&amp;keywords=pizza&amp;scrambleSeed=721890588&amp;pageNum=5" data-tracking="DISPLAY:PAGINATION:NUMBER">5</a>
&nbsp;<a class="pagination--page" rel="nofollow" href="/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?location=United+Kingdom&amp;keywords=pizza&amp;scrambleSeed=721890588&amp;pageNum=6" data-tracking="DISPLAY:PAGINATION:NUMBER">6</a>
&nbsp;<a class="pagination--page" rel="nofollow" href="/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?location=United+Kingdom&amp;keywords=pizza&amp;scrambleSeed=721890588&amp;pageNum=7" data-tracking="DISPLAY:PAGINATION:NUMBER">7</a>
&nbsp;<a class="pagination--page" rel="nofollow" href="/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?location=United+Kingdom&amp;keywords=pizza&amp;scrambleSeed=721890588&amp;pageNum=8" data-tracking="DISPLAY:PAGINATION:NUMBER">8</a>
&nbsp;<a class="pagination--page" rel="nofollow" href="/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?location=United+Kingdom&amp;keywords=pizza&amp;scrambleSeed=721890588&amp;pageNum=9" data-tracking="DISPLAY:PAGINATION:NUMBER">9</a>
&nbsp;<a class="pagination--page" rel="nofollow" href="/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?location=United+Kingdom&amp;keywords=pizza&amp;scrambleSeed=721890588&amp;pageNum=10" data-tracking="DISPLAY:PAGINATION:NUMBER">10</a>
&nbsp;<a rel="nofollow" class="pagination--next" href="/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?location=United+Kingdom&amp;keywords=pizza&amp;scrambleSeed=721890588&amp;pageNum=2" data-tracking="DISPLAY:PAGINATION:NEXT">Next</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the fact that the very first page is selected already and so it doesn't have an anchor in the pagination. Solution would be to process the first page first and then process the remaining pages using pagination. HTH

```
Option Explicit

Sub YellUK()
Const mlink = "https://www.yell.com"
Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim page As Object, newlink As String

With http
    .Open "GET", "https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?keywords=pizza&location=United+Kingdom&scrambleSeed=1426936001", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Set page = html.getElementsByClassName("row pagination")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")

Dim i, x
' First page first, is selected already, 'row pagination' doesn't have 'a' for it
GetPageData x, html

' Next pages then
Dim html2 As New HTMLDocument
For i = 0 To page.Length - 2
    newlink = mlink & Replace(page(i).href, "about:", "")
    With http
        .Open "GET", newlink, False
        .send
        html2.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    GetPageData x, html2
Next i
End Sub

Private Sub GetPageData(ByRef x, ByRef html As HTMLDocument)
    Dim post As HTMLHtmlElement
    For Each post In html.getElementsByClassName("js-LocalBusiness")
        x = x + 1
        With post.getElementsByClassName("row businessCapsule--title")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
            If .Length Then Cells(x + 1, 1) = .Item(0).innerText
        End With
        With post.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-10 col-md-11 col-lg-12 businessCapsule--address")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")
            If .Length > 1 Then Cells(x + 1, 2) = .Item(1).innerText
        End With
        With post.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-10 col-md-11 col-lg-12 businessCapsule--address")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")
            If .Length > 2 Then Cells(x + 1, 3) = .Item(2).innerText
        End With
        With post.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-10 col-md-11 col-lg-12 businessCapsule--address")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")
            If .Length > 3 Then Cells(x + 1, 4) = .Item(3).innerText
        End With
        With post.getElementsByClassName("businessCapsule--tel")
            If .Length > 1 Then Cells(x + 1, 5) = .Item(1).innerText
        End With
    Next post
End Sub
```

EDIT:
Could be something like this. The first page link is created for `i=-1` and then the next pages as ussual.

```
For i = -1 To page.Length - 2
    If i = -1 Then
        newlink = mlink & Replace(page(i + 1).href, "about:", "")
        newlink = Left(newlink, Len(newlink) - 1) & "1"
    Else
        newlink = mlink & Replace(page(i).href, "about:", "")
    End If
    Debug.Print i & ", " & newlink ' Prints the links for all the pages
    With http
        .Open "GET", newlink, False
        .send
        htm.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    ' Get page data here ...
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks sir dee, it is always a great pleasure to have you in the loop. Your solution does get the whole content. Ain't it possible to make the whole thing in a single subroutine?

Comment: You are welcome! It would be possible e.g. to prepare the `URLs` first (including the first page and then loop through this `URLs`. Otherwise as I wrote: the first page is currently loaded and it doesn't have any `a` element in the pagination control (which is logical, because pagination control contains links to next pages).

Comment: Please sir, a little more explanation on how i can get there myself to do the whole stuff in a single subroutine.

Comment: Thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss a trillion in advance.

Comment: Thanks sir dee, for the edit. It works like magic. I wish I could hit the upvote button million times.

Comment: You are welcome sir @SMth80! One upvote is enough, thanks :). You will have to add some more code for cases when no results were found or when just one page is returned etc.